# How do you modify the current selection length in a Tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, string, text, tkinter

I would like to be able to double click on `test,`
in a Tkinter Text widget, and have it select test (and exclude the comma).

Here is what I've tried:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def selection_mod(event=None):
    result = aText.selection_get().find(',')
    if result > 0:
        try:
            aText.tag_add("sel", "sel.first", "sel.last-1c")
        except tk.TclError:
            pass

lord = tk.Tk()

aText = tk.Text(lord, font=("Georgia", "12"))
aText.grid()

aText.bind("<Double-Button-1>", selection_mod)

lord.mainloop()
```

The first issue is that `<Double-Button-1>` seems to trigger the handler before the selection is made, producing:

> TclError: PRIMARY selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined

The second issue is that even when using a binding that works,
my selection tag doesn't seem to do anything.
It doesn't even raise an error, and I've tried without the `except tk.TclError:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding is happening before the default bindings occur. Thus, the selection doesn't yet exist when your binding fires. Because your binding tries to get the selection, it fails with the error that you see.

You will need to arrange for your binding to happen after the class bindings. A cheap hack is to use `after` to execute your code once the default bindings have a chance to work. Or, you can use the `bindtag` feature to make sure your binding fires after the default bindings.

The second problem is that you don't clear the old selection before setting the new. You'll want to do `tag_remove` to first remove the existing selection. Otherwise, the comma (if it was somehow selected) will remain selected since all you're doing is re-applying the tag to text that already has the tag.

However, double-click doesn't normally capture the comma so I don't quite understand then point of your code. At least, when I test it on OSX it doesn't include the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with thanks to Bryan's answer:

```
import Tkinter as tki # tkinter in Python 3

def selection_mod(event=None):
    result = txt.selection_get().find(',')
    if result > 0:
       fir, sec = txt.tag_ranges("sel")
       txt.tag_remove("sel", "sel.first", "sel.last")
       txt.tag_add("sel", fir, str(sec)+"-1c")

root = tki.Tk()

txt = tki.Text(root, font=("Georgia", "12"))
txt.grid()

txt.bind("<Double-Button-1>", lambda x: root.after(20, selection_mod))

root.mainloop()
```

It's worth noting that I'm using Windows 7, and according to Bryan,
OSX doesn't include the comma when you double click a word.

Comment: I recently discovered how to set what characters are selected with tcl. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28133301/1217270)